# Need to have a dynamic E-Mail-Notification

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am in the Testautomation and we are testing for different Projects. This Projects can have some different variants in it. I want to have for all Projects and Variants only one generic Test, so that i do not have to change some things 10 times.
Right now it is working fine but the problem is, that for each project and variant, the test have to send a mail to different people. How can i do that with jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the editiable email plugin. And use the post section of your pipeline with the extmail step to send out individual email from alls your projects and variants. Use switch case or if scripts to select the right audience.

```
post{
   script: {
       if ( ){
          extemail
```